# problem with using javascript to load Quicktime into div from link

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, quicktime

I have a left `<div>` (id = 'videopane')  and a right `<div>` containing a clickable list of items.

I am trying program this: You click on one of the items in the right `<div>`, it loads the Quicktime movie into the left `<div>`.

I am using the [JQuery media plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) to generate all of the embed code. and it works if I simply input the code `<a class="media" href="anthony-mandler/music-video/Rihanna_Only_Girl_Web.mov"></a>` into the left `<div>`.

It does not work when I try to apply this code to one of the items in the list in the right `<div>`, although the code seems fine to me:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('videopane').innerHTML='&lt;a class=&quot;media&quot; href=&quot;anthony-mandler/music-video/Rihanna_Only_Girl_Web.mov&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;'">
```

Any insight into what I am doing wrong?

Comment: the plugin you have format the anchor tag on page load. anychange you make after that are not going to have any effect. try runing the script on click

Comment: Found the solution from the plugin's website, although I happened upon it through google groups:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/media/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin you are using is taking the movie source from the `href` of the link. So you would do it link this.

```
<a title="movie title" class="media" href="anthony-mandler/music-video/Rihanna_Only_Girl_Web.mov" />
```

This will generate when clicked.

```
<div class="media"> 
    <object codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" 
        classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"> 
        <param name="src" value="anthony-mandler/music-video/Rihanna_Only_Girl_Web.mov"> 
        <embed src="sample.mov" 
            pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed> 
    </object> 
    <div>My Quicktime Movie</div> 
</div>
```

Make sure to add this after you include jQuery and the plugin.

```
$('.media').media();
```

Comment: This is just the standard link for the plugin I am using which will just load the movie on page load where ever you put the <a> tag.

Comment: Found the solution from the plugin's website, although I happened upon it through google groups:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/media/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

html that is generated on the fly will not work, right away,

make sure that when you add the anchor tag to run the plug in function:

```
<a href="#" id='rihana' >Rihana</a>
```

Javascript

```
var movie = document.getElementById('rihana');

movie.onclick = function () {
   document.getElementById('videopane').innerHTML= '<a title="movie title" class="media" href="anthony-mandler/music-video/Rihanna_Only_Girl_Web.mov" />'

// then run the plugin function.
$('.media').media();
```

Comment: This may work for one movie file, but I don't see how it will work for a list of links to different movie files.

Comment: Found the solution from the plugin's website, although I happened upon it through google groups:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/media/replace.html